# Muting/Unmuting speakers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, windows-7

I'm trying to create a piece of Malware that plays an audio file and doesn't allow the user to easily cancel play of the file. I've tested some code from https://python-forum.io/Thread-How-to-change-the-sound-volume-with-python and ran into an issue. The following code does change the volume levels of the computer but it doesn't unmute it. EX:

```
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume

devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
interface = devices.Activate(
   IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))

# Control volume
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-0.0, None) #max
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-5.0, None) #72%
volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(-10.0, None) #51%
```

I'm creating this malware as a student project so would appreciate some help (I'm also not incredibly familiar with libraries past some very basic Python libraries.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because malware is bad. Ok?

Comment: Assuming this is for educational purpose, Check example here on how to mute/unmute using `pycaw`. https://github.com/AndreMiras/pycaw/blob/develop/examples/volume_by_process_example.py

Comment: Thank you for the example. This is for educational purposes as it's part of my school project.

Comment: Do you know if there would be a way to unmute the speaker/device itself? Unmuting the application is useful but the user is still able to just mute the device and stop all audio.

Answer (score 1):

0 means unmute

```py
volume.SetMute(0, None)
```